# what is this code mean std::vector<cv::Point2f> points[2]

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to convert some c++ with opencv code to matlab , but I do not understand this line of code ,I know this declare a vector of type point2f (float points of 2 nodes x,y for ex) but I do not understand point[2] this confusing me 
Can any one explain this line of code to me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type variable_name[n]` declares an array of `n` elements of type `type`, with the name `variable_name`.

Thus `std::vector<cv::Point2f> points[2]` declares an array of two `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` elements. The name of that array is `points`.